# akka-persistence-cassandra too many reads from metadata table

Tags: scala, optimization, cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

We have a multi node web application that uses akka-persistence-cassandra to store incoming events. Recently we were told that our application is doing nearly 2.8mln reads per day from cassandra `messages` and `metadata` table.(combined) I understand the need to read from `messages` table but i am still not able to figure out why we need to read from `metadata` table.

Lets look at akka-persistence-cassandra api  (2.11-0.59) . This is the only read query on metadata table

```
def selectDeletedTo = s"""
  SELECT deleted_to FROM ${metadataTableName} WHERE
    persistence_id = ?
"""
```

The `CassandraJournal` class implements this [asyncReadHighestSequenceNr](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/persistence/journal/AsyncWriteJournal.html#asyncReadHighestSequenceNr(persistenceId:String,fromSequenceNr:Long):scala.concurrent.Future[Long]) :

```
override def asyncReadHighestSequenceNr(persistenceId: String, fromSequenceNr: Long): Future[Long] = {
    writeInProgress.get(persistenceId) match {
      case null => super.asyncReadHighestSequenceNr(persistenceId, fromSequenceNr)
      case f    => f.flatMap(_ => super.asyncReadHighestSequenceNr(persistenceId, fromSequenceNr))
    }
  }

override def asyncReadHighestSequenceNr(persistenceId: String, fromSequenceNr: Long): Future[Long] =
    asyncHighestDeletedSequenceNumber(persistenceId).flatMap { h =>
      asyncFindHighestSequenceNr(persistenceId, math.max(fromSequenceNr, h))
    }
```

So as i can understand from the above statement, akka  first needs to read the metadata table to get the deleted count and then use that to get the highest sequence number.

**However in my application i never delete a message so `metadata` table is always empty** . Hence `math.max(fromSequenceNr, h)` will always result in fromSequenceNr.

So i am thinking of overriding `asyncReadHighestSequenceNr` method and removing the call to read highest deleted seq number. That should save me all the extra calls to `metadata` table..

Any comments , ideas on how this sounds??

Comment: sounds reasonable to me. I'll have to test the integration, but if the metadata table is always empty, this is a wasted operation and should be overridden.